# Lost with MySql updating issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 2 scripts that are working fine.

One updates a db by posting an artist title and album via url.

The other pulls the last row and displays it on a joomla site.

Id like to have this update in the browser without a full page refresh. Everytime a new song loads or the table is updated, it should show the latest table on the page. Alternatively, I'd be fine just having it check every minute or so for a new song.

I'm totally new to this so any direction to how I can learn how to do this would be appreciated.

There are tons of how tos with drop downs or querys, I just want to update this automatically with no user interaction. Thanks...

Comment: You've already answered your question with the tags. A bit of jquery to poll the server via AJAX requests. The server-side handler would send back the new data or a "nothing's changed" message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX technique and periodical update your page, [here](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/periodicalUpdater) described the easiest and simpliest way to do things as you wish with Prototype javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example (works in Chrome) using jQuery. The #data div will be updated with the contents of /pull_last_row_from_db.php every 10 seconds.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="data"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval('update_data()', 10000); // Called every 10 seconds
        }
    );

    function update_data() {
        // Do AJAX call
        var params = { foo: 'bar', example: 2 };
        $.get('/pull_last_row_from_db.php', params,
            function(response) {
                $('#data').html(response);
            }
        );
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```